# Internationalize t inputFileupload Browse Button

Tags: internationalization, tomahawk

How to internationalize browse button in fileupload component?
I’m using t:inputFileupload and i searched it in net but not able to find a solution.

Please give me one solution.

Thanks in advance.
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

The only ways are:

- create your own (i.e.) Flash control
- set this control transparency to 100% and place your own button on it ("skin" it specifically)

This is unfortunately HTML limitation.